# Why string can't be split at \r\n?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string containing \r\n. I am unable to split it. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
let xyz = String(JSON.stringify(data[property].Users__c));
            let arr = xyz.split("\r\n");
            console.log('XYZ :' + xyz);
            console.log('ARR: ' + arr);
```

SS of Edge:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you've a string containing literal backslashes (`\\r\\n`) instead of the CR + LF characters.

Comment: `xyz.split(/\\r\\n/)` may work

Comment: Or if CR + LF is there, just drop all the overly complex string handling before splitting: `arr = (data[property].Users__c).split('\r\n');`.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `JSON.stringify` on a string, newline characters are escaped and the string is wrapped in quotes. It looks like you want neither to happen. Note also that applying `String` to a string is useless.

So just drop those two function calls:

```
let xyz = data[property].Users__c;
let arr = xyz.split("\r\n");
console.log('XYZ :' + xyz);
console.log('ARR: ' + arr);
```

If for some reason the `Users__c` property would be some other data type than a string, then the question is what you expect `split` to produce... You could keep the `String` call to avoid errors in that case, but you'd need to look into what you then really want to happen:

```
let xyz = String(data[property].Users__c);
let arr = xyz.split("\r\n");
console.log('XYZ :' + xyz);
console.log('ARR: ' + arr);
```